# I would like to install pip packages on a Linux CentOS without internet access

Tags: linux, centos, windows, pip

I have a Linux CentOS without internet access and I need to install some python packages.

My pc runs Windows 8.1

Can I download the .whl files and send them with WinSCP ?

From where can I download manually pip packages for Linux ? Because if I download with pip on windows the files are .exe

Thanks in advance

Comment: Available packages, CentOS http://mirror.centos.org/centos/